# Pass Product Object to the sales_quote_save_before event in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento

I wouldl like to pass the product object to the observer, however, i can not find the dispatch method of the event sales_quote_save_before

can any one tell me where I can put the product object into the related observer?
thanks

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <sales_quote_save_before> 
            <observers>
                <inchoo_maxorderamount_enforceSingleOrderLimit>
                    <class>inchoo_maxorderamount/observer</class>
                    <method>enforceSingleOrderLimit</method>
                </inchoo_maxorderamount_enforceSingleOrderLimit>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_save_before>
    </events>
</frontend>

public function enforceSingleOrderLimit($observer)
{
    if (!$this->_helper->isModuleEnabled()) {
        return;
    }
    $p = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    echo $p->getProductId();
    die();
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    $action = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();
    if ($action != 'index'){
    if ((float)$quote->getItemsQty() > (float)$this->_helper->getSingleOrderTopAmount()) {
        $max = $this->_helper->getSingleOrderTopAmount();
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError(
        $this->_helper->__('Max quantity allowed', $max));
        $url = Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer() ? Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer()  : Mage::getUrl();
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();

        exit;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to loop through all the products in the quote?

Comment: no, i just need to get the newly added product, not the whole cart, thx

Comment: Therefore you should observe "sales_quote_**item**_save_before" event. There would be a product entity (product_id least) withinin the quote item passed to your observer

Comment: Hello Neklo.com , i pasted my observer here, can you see why still cannot get the current product which added to cart? i have already used

    $p = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    echo $p->getProductId();

Comment: you can use **sales_quote_item_set_product** event